# Split tuple and get N-th element

Tags: bash, shell-script, python

I need to split the tuple value returned from python script and get particular value (in my case an array) and assign it to the bash array.

**Tuple returned from python:**

```py
   (1,2,[3,4],[5,6])   # dynamic array size # tuple size will always be 4
```

Is there anyway i can do like, say `array1=tuple[2] and array2=tuple[3]` without splitting using any delimiters and IFS stuffs?

Any easy way would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't your Python script output something that's more bash-friendly? Something's going to have to do the "splitting using any delimiters and IFS stuffs", might as well get Python to do it.

Comment: On exiting all python resources will be cleared as you know, so bash will maintain those two index values and array values and then pass for next iteration to python script which then modifies and returns the new array.